# Need to get the X and Y value of image where it clicked I am using image which larger then device in android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, canvas

Hi, I know how to get the clicked position in screen  .. my problem is I need to get the X and Y value of image where it clicked. It works fine if I have image size lesser then device but it goes wrong when using the large image.

I am Using horizontal and vertical scroll view to show the large image.

Using  the `event.getX()` to get the position in the touch listener.

Comment: Account for the offset that the image is clipped by and you'll get your coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Can you explain it more 
"iccthedral" . i am new to android .

Answer (score 0):

To get X and Y value on image put following code in OnTouchListener.

```
public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent ev) 
{
    final int action = ev.getAction();

    final int evX = (int) ev.getX();
    final int evY = (int) ev.getY();
}
```

Comment: i know this code i am using this for get the clicked position of the image my problem is when i use a large image the position was wrong ... that mean a particular part of the image only shown so the clicked position only consider the visible image..